# jQuery ignores else if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I am working on a web app where the user is asked to add an "application" by entering the StudentID and JobID. I am using jQuery to let the user know when a student that they entered doesn't exist, a job doesn't exist,the application already exists on the database or when the application has been added successfully. I check everything on the backend using PHP and send the message to the frontend to display that to the user.

Everything works fine until the if-statement which I use to decide the message that I will display to the user based on the message received from the backend.

jQuery completely ignores the 'else if' statements. If the first condition it true, it executes its body successfully, however, if the first one isn't true it goes straight to the else statement, ignoring the else if statements even if they are true.

Here is the code:

```
var myData = {"tablename": tablename, "StudentId": StudentId, "JobId": JobId};
            $.ajax({
                url: "insert.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: myData,
                success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                    console.log(data);
                    if (data =="success") {
                        $('#message').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
                        $('#StudentId').val('');
                        $('#JobId').val('');
                    } else if(data=="fail") {

                        $('#message5').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();

                    } else if (data =="student"){

                        $('#message2').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
                    }
                      else if (data == "job"){

                        $('#message3').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
                    }
                      else  {

                        $('#message4').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
                    }
                }

            });
```

Comment: I can assure you Javascript does not miss conditions out. You should really look at the console to check for syntax errors.

Comment: Why do you have a condition in your last `else`? (`else (data == "studentjob")`)

Comment: you miss an if in the last item ("studentjob"). BTW have you considered using a switch statement?

Comment: So open up the developer console and read the error message that the JavaScript is throwing.

Comment: Why would anyone vote to close it down? it's supposed to be a place where people come in to ask questions that they can't find the answers to (especially junior developers). You can't just discourage people from even asking questions when they don't know something. If you feel like this is a stupid question, just skip it - ON TO THE NEXT ONE!

Comment: Looks like this question was abandoned.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you not use `switch` statement ? I recommend you use it. The `switch` statement is used to perform different actions based on different conditions.

Now your code should work. Here is solution:

```
switch(data){
        case "success":
          $('#message').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
          $('#StudentId').val('');
          $('#JobId').val('');
          break;
       case "fail":
          $('#message5').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();  
          break;
       case "student":
          $('#message2').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
          break;
       case "job":
          $('#message3').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
          break;
       case "studentjob":
          $('#message4').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
          break;                
}
```

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't work. I did console.log(data) to see if it gets the correct error message and it does but it still ignores the conditions even when using switch. And btw, it doesn't throw any errors in console.

Comment: @useruser1412, can you post your `data` json ?

Answer (score 1):

Just as an example of a way to test, I've created a plunker for you

An easy strategy is to just create test buttons that force the response you want to test, and mash it until it works right.  Ideally, you'd create unit tests and test against that, but I can imagine what you're doing is prohibitively simple to go that route.

E.g. from plunkr:

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <button onclick="testSuccess()">Success</button>
  <button onclick="testFail()">Fail</button>
  <button onclick="testStudent()">Student</button>
  <button onclick="testJob()">Job</button>
  <button onclick="testStudentJob()">Student Job</button>
  <button onclick="testUnexpected()">Unexpected</button>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var testSuccess = function() {
  successFn("success");
}

var testFail = function() {
  successFn("fail");
}

var testStudent = function() {
  successFn("student");
}

var testJob = function() {
  successFn("job");
}

var testStudentJob = function() {
  successFn("studentjob");
}

var testUnexpected = function() {
  successFn("somethingSilly");
}
```

Refactor your http call:

```
var myData = {"tablename": tablename, "StudentId": StudentId, "JobId": JobId};
            $.ajax({
                url: "insert.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: myData,
                success: successFn 
            });
```

And slightly modify your if-else (highly recommend going with Alexandru Mihai's suggestion of switch statements here)

```
 var successFn = function (data, status, xhr) {
                console.log(data);
                if (data =="success") {
                    $('#message').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
                    $('#StudentId').val('');
                    $('#JobId').val('');
                } 
                else if(data=="fail") {

                    $('#message5').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();

                } 
                else if (data =="student"){

                    $('#message2').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
                }
                else if (data == "job"){

                    $('#message3').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
                }
                else if (data == "studentjob") {

                    $('#message4').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
                }
                else {
                  alert('Unexpected response');
                }
            };
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/KZrWMrcybko6P32yFopz

Comment: it doesn't throw any errors in console though. it just ignores the else if statements.

Comment: The plnkr works.  Show more of your code if you must.  I would suggest refactoring as I have and running test responses through (as suggested in my plunker).  That way you can isolate integration errors form logic errors.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your if-block, the last `else` has a condition. This should show up as an error in the console.

Either change `else (data == "studentjob")` to

```
else
```

or

```
else if (data == "studentjob")
```

Comment: I must have added it unintentionally before I posted the question but I just tried it without it and it still doesn't work